# how to obscure database credentials on a javascript MVC framework like angular

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs

In an mvc framework like angularjs, so far examples ive found stores the database credentials in an app.constant property in an app.js file, this is easily readable by users

in my case im connecting to mongolab via a service loaded from a mongolab.js file. my apikey is defined in there, and of course i have no access to the mongolab backend to have it receive a hash

what would be best practice to tackle this? preferably with pointers to some material i can study.

Comment: https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/angularjs-mongolab-promise/issues/9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you connect to mongolab server side? Clientside will always be at risk, even if you use encryption.

In angular, you would have a service (using `app.factory()`), which connects via your [service layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_oriented_architecture) (using jsonp or another format), which will check his 'connector table' to call the right (external) service. Here is a very simple scheme:

```
Client (js) --> Server (java, php, ...) --> Service 1
                                        --> Service 2
```

Comment: care to elaborate on your preferred setup? what i can imagine from what you said is something like a REST service?

Comment: can it be something simple like a single php file that handles database queries, and then i use angular's $http service to send a request to this file?

Comment: Added a paragraph to my answer.

Comment: that is how i have it set up curently, the service layer (if i am understanding you correctly) is a mongolab.js file, which gets called as part of the markup, im following the example on angular's website. so what kind of service layer can obscure this?